# Problem adding field to a custom list type in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, exception, spfield, spfieldcollection

I have defined a **custom list template type for SharePoint**. I install it using VSeWSS 1.3 and everything seems to behave correctly.

I have added a custom action which will **add additional columns (SPFields) to the list**. However, every time that code executes it throws and ArgumentException with a **'Value not in the expected range.'** error message. This behavior seems to be specific to custom types as suggested in [this blog post](http://www.pings.dk/blog/archive/2008/04/22/problem-with-a-custom-content-type-when-performing-a-check-in.aspx).

Here is the relevant code (thisList is an instance of my custom list template type created using the browser interace) that tries to add a field to the SPFieldCollection of thisList:

```
                SPFieldType fieldType = Format2SPFieldType(format);
                SPField field = new SPField(thisList.Fields, fieldType.ToString(), fieldName);
                thisList.Fields.Add(field);
```

The last statement (thisList.Fields.Add(field)) throws the following exception:

```
   Message  "Value does not fall within the expected range."

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXmlInternal(String schemaXml, Boolean addToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions op)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml(String schemaXml, Boolean addToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions op)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.Add(SPField field)
```

This same code executes just fine if the SPList item is the base list type (built-in custom list).

Are there any **fields that need to be set explicitly** in the **CAML** and using the **AddFieldAsXml() method** directly to make this code work with custom list template types?

**Update:** I should also mention that the fields are actually created in some instances even though the call throws an exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was caused **because calling thisList.SchemaXML put the SPList object into a state that I wasn't able to recover from!** Getting a new reference to the same SharePoint List, e.g., SPList newList=thisList.ParentWeb.Lists[thisList.ID] solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

What is the Type of Field you are trying to add? is that an Internal field or a Custom Field type, what does this Function Format2SPFieldType return?
If it is a Inbuilt field can you try adding with the

```
thisList.Fields.Add("DisplayName", SPFieldType.Integer, false);
```

Comment: I am trying to add regular types like the one you mention above. The Format2SPFieldType function returns and SPFieldType (it is a switch statement that maps a format string to an SPFieldType). So far I have tried SPFieldType.Text and SPFieldType.Boolean.